# My python perfect number function returns invalid data

Tags: python, numbers, perfect-numbers

I finally got the perfect number program that I am writing in Python to work...just not correctly.

I have run the code 3 times and it keeps returning 24 as a perfect number.

```
def printPerfectNumbers(firstNum, lastNum):
 
   for i in range(firstNum, lastNum +1):
       totalFactors = 0
       for x in range(1, i):
       # Checks if x is a divisor, if true, adds x to totalFactors.
         if(i % x == 0):
             totalFactors = totalFactors + x
             if (totalFactors == i):
                print(i, end = " ")

printPerfectNumbers(1, 1000)
```

Any advice would be welcome.

Answer (score 3):

```
         if (totalFactors == i):
            print(i, end = " ")
```

needs to be 2 levels less since you want to check the sum `totalFactors` only after all possible candidate divisors have been looked at:

```
def printPerfectNumbers(firstNum, lastNum):
 
   for i in range(firstNum, lastNum +1):
       totalFactors = 0
       for x in range(1, i):
       # Checks if x is a divisor, if true, adds x to totalFactors.
           if(i % x == 0):
               totalFactors = totalFactors + x
       if (totalFactors == i):
           print(i, end = " ")

printPerfectNumbers(1, 1000)
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you so much.

Comment: PS: you should aim to use consistent indentation too... (e.g. always multiples of 4 spaces)

Answer (score -1):

That's simple.
1+2+3+4+6+8=24
You should compare the sum and double of the original number after `for`.